# symfony2 entity field send a null POST Request

Tags: php, symfony

I create a form in my controller :

```
public function uploadAction(Request $request)
    {

        $user= new User();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('app_create_user'))
            ->add('name','text',array('label'=>'Your Name','required' => false))
            ->add('idcountry', 'entity', array(
                'mapped'   => false, 
                'class'    => 'GedBundle:Country',
                'property' => 'country_name',
                'label'     => 'Your Country',
            ))

            ->add('file')
            ->getForm()
        ;

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_homepage'));

            }
        }

        return $this->render('GedBundle:Default:form.html.twig',array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }
```

And here is my view :

```
<form action=" {{ path('app_create_user') }} " method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
 {{ form_widget(form) }}
 <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

everything works well, but the only problem is when I submitted the form the value of idcountry send as null an I get this error "The field 'idcountry' can not be empty". What is the problem ?

Comment: Just check your entity once. If it is required property then add 'nullable' attribute to that property.

Comment: Is the error on the form or is it thrown up as an exception when you try to persist? Also you are creating `$user` but are then persisting `$document` (probably a type, I know).

Comment: I choose a choice in  dropdown, butt the form send the country value as null

Comment: @Qoop No I persiste $user, a edit my question

Comment: Can you post the request data with a `print_r($request->request);`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mapped = false` config settings from `idcountry`, because that means, the property will be available from `$form->getData()` as a separate array element and not part of your user entity.

BTW, which version of symfony are you using? Cause over 2.3 it's recommended to use like this:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    //YOUR CODE
}
```

and not to use bindRequest and method checking.

Comment: I did what you said, but I get an error Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Counrty could not be converted to string , So I add __toString function in Country Class but I get this error Method __toString() must not throw an exception :/

Comment: Can you add also your country object? And what does it say, where is it throwing an exception with the __toString?